# How to add two or more icons to a textField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a text field with a value. But I ran into a problem that I need to add icons next to the value in addition to the value. I can add one icon using suffixIcon. But I will need to add 3 icons, sometimes add 2 icons but I don't know how to add more than one icon to the text field?

```
Widget _defaultTextfield(
    bool enabled,
    TextInputType? type,
    String hint,
    String val,
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    final MycarsCubit cubit = BlocProvider.of<MycarsCubit>(context);
    return SizedBox(
      height: 58,
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        color: constants.Colors.greyMiddle,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                style: constants.Styles.smallTextStyleWhite,
                keyboardType: type,
                controller: TextEditingController(text: '$val kW'),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  cubit.change(
                    carModelNew: cubit.carModel,
                    idText: cubit.id,
                    modelText: cubit.model,
                    numberText: value,
                    typeText: cubit.type,
                    yearText: cubit.year,
                    chargeSpeedText: cubit.chargeSpeed,
                    connectorText: cubit.connector,
                    batteryCapacityText: cubit.batteryCapacity,
                    mainNew: cubit.main,
                  );
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  enabled: enabled,
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  labelText: hint,
                  labelStyle: constants.Styles.textFieldLabelLightGreyStyle,
                  suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.bolt),
                  suffixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxHeight: 10
                  )
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixIcon: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.bolt),
                  value == 10 ? Icon(Icons.bolt):SizedBox(),
                  
                ],
              )),
            )
```

Comment: and how can I check if the value is 5 then display 1 icon, if the value is 10 then display 2 icons?

Comment: Is that what you want? if you tell me the conditions I can help you better.

Comment: I will check now and let you know

Comment: Can't make suffixIcon be next to value in textbox? Like in the screenshot. It's just that otherwise I have it at the end of the text field

Comment: I updated the question and added a screenshot of how my icons are added now and how far they are

Comment: suffixIcon is a widget that sit at the end of  textField. If you want it to be close to the value you should use bolt symbol unicode and add it to your value.bolt symbol unicode is 26a1

Comment: but then I won't be able to change the unicode color?

Comment: unfortunately you can not.